# Group Results & Count Values In While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query that lists the employees name, the hours/minutes they have worked and the cost for those hours.  Here is the query, it joins 3 tables:

```
$usersResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.UF_TIME_ID, a.UF_USER, a.UF_COST,
b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME, c.ID, c.MINUTES, c.TASK_ID FROM time_cost a INNER
JOIN b_user b ON a.UF_USER = b.ID INNER JOIN b_tasks_elapsed_time c ON 
a.UF_TIME_ID = c.ID GROUP BY a.UF_USER");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult)
```

The minutes field is simply will read 120 for the number of minutes.  I then have a function that splits this into hours and minutes.  From this in the loop I get a table that looks like:

```
NAME          | Time Spent    | Cost
Bob           | 2h 30m        | 50
Bob           | 2h 15m        | 40
Dave          | 3h 30m        | 120
Bob           | 1h 15m        | 20
Dave          | 4h 30m        | 180
```

Now I want to group them, I have tried to GROUP BY a.UF_USER but it doesn't add the time or costs up correctly which I can understand.  I have then tried:

```
SUM(c.MINUTES) AS TOTAL
```

And used that with and without the GROUP but that also doesn't add the values up correctly.  I have also tried:

```
$totalTime += $row['MINUTES'];
```

But again with grouping it doesn't display.  Here is the code after the while loop I have:

```
   {
   $userFirstName = $row['NAME'];
   $userLastName = $row['LAST_NAME'];
   $userCost = $row['UF_COST'];
   $userMinutes = $row['MINUTES'];


   $userTime = $userMinutes;
   $userTime = convertFromMinutes($userTime);


   $totaluserHours = $userTime['hours'];
   $totaluserMinutes = $userTime['minutes'];

   print "<tr><td>$userFirstName $userLastName</td><td>$totaluserHours H $totaluserMinutes M</td><td>$userCost</td></tr>"; 
   }
```

I have a function that counts the minutes and splits into hours and minutes.  So I need the end outcome to basically read:

```
NAME          | Time Spent    | Cost
Bob           | 6h 00m        | 110
Dave          | 8h 00m        | 300
```

Your help would greatly be appreciated.  I'm sure it is simple and I'm missing the point here.

Comment: You should describe what is in the hours and minutes fields (give us some sample data) and then provide us with expected output and the output you get when you tried the various solutions.

Comment: use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for give us sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for get ths add you need a sum

try this way

```
$usersResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.UF_TIME_ID, a.UF_USER, sum(a.UF_COST),
b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME, c.ID, sum(c.MINUTES), c.TASK_ID FROM time_cost a  INNER
JOIN b_user b ON a.UF_USER = b.ID INNER JOIN b_tasks_elapsed_time c ON 
 a.UF_TIME_ID = c.ID GROUP BY a.UF_USER");
```

Comment: Wow, I was not using sum on both so it wasn't adding one and excluding the other.  I knew it was a simple solution I was missing.